# How to cross the straits of gibraltar?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Was curious how the mechanics worked.

Did I need to load regiments into transports first and then unload them?

Or can I just dock 1 transport in province below and then move my regiments across. Without unloading and loading the regiments?

Does the number of transports determine the number of regiments I can move across, or is 1 enough to move an army of 30 across?

Does blockading ships block this movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, blockades block troop transport ships.

The only ships that can carry troops are transport ships, such as cogs and brigades, and you need to have sufficient number of transport ships to carry all the regiments in your army. If your army is 5,000-men-at-arms strong, then 5 transport ships are necessary to carry them all, otherwise you need to split your movements.

You can "attach to transport" so that when you move your ships, the troops at port will go with them automatically.

Or, in a recent expansion, you can designate ships to be used automatically for transport, so that you can simply move the troops from one port to another and the loading and unloading and shipping will happen automatically, greatly reducing the number of steps required.

Answer (score 1):

The straits that can be crossed without transports are marked with dashed red lines. You can fine these, for example, between the isles of Denmark, at Constantinople and Black Sea. The Gibraltar strait however requires transport ships. The reason for that is purely technical